# eliminate error in generated xjb file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My project generates the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
  version="2.1">

  <!-- from codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/jaxxb-xjc-code-generation-adding-xmlrootelement-and-joda-datetime -->  

  <!-- Application of annotations to selected classes within schemas -->

  <!-- org.example.SomeRootType @XmlRootElement -->
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="domain1.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='SomeRootType']">
      <annox:annotate>
        <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="SomeRootType"/>
      </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

eclipse then reports an error on the "jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes" line

> cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes' is not allowed to appear in element 
>    'jaxb:bindings'.

I don't know what tool is generating the file; annox.dev.java.jet appears to be a subtool that allows annotations in XML, but I cannot find any XML files in the project, generated or otherwise, that use annotations.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the error, or at least the error message? I hate leaving error marks in my projects that don't indicate real errors; it makes it harder to notice when I actually have an error.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `xsi:schemaLocation`. The schema you use is not correct. It does declare `jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes` attribute but does not use it in `jaxb:bindings`.

Comment: I tried that, but this is a *GENERATED* file. Generated, as in, I didn't write it and cannot change what it looks like.

Comment: You can postprocess a generated file with XSLT or something similar.